# Create a vector within a Loop in R

Tags: r, tree, nested-loops

I have the following code:

```
    generator <- function(n){
  nodes <- c()
  distances <- c()
  for (main in 1:n){
    for (i in 1:n) {
      for (j in 1:n){
        if (main != i & i != j & main != j & i < j){
          nodes <- c(nodes, paste(main, i, j, sep=",", collapse=""))
          distances <- c(distances, main+i+j)}}}}
  data <- data.frame(nodes, distances)
  return(data)}
```

Running generator(4), I get the following output:

```
      nodes distances
1  1,2,3         6
2  1,2,4         7
3  1,3,4         8
4  2,1,3         6
5  2,1,4         7
6  2,3,4         9
7  3,1,2         6
8  3,1,4         8
9  3,2,4         9
10 4,1,2         7
11 4,1,3         8
12 4,2,3         9
```

What I would like is to have the items in the "nodes" column be actual vectors of values, with the goal of comparing different triplets of nodes and finding the common members. It is currently just a string. So, for instance, I would like `a$nodes[1][1]`, to yield `1`, or something along those lines, so I can extract every individual value from the `nodes` triplets.

I currently have `paste(main, i, j, sep=",")` and I tried replacing this with `c(main, i, j)` but what happened is that I got a data frame of 36 rows instead of twelve: each individual node was its own row.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you add the library calls ?

Comment: There are a lot of user-defined functions and simulated data here, it would not be necessary.

Comment: You might want to modify your example to make it reproducible then, you'll get higher quality answers and it'll be more helpful for future readers

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, the example is now reproducible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to work with list columns to do what you want to do.

I suggest working with tibbles instead of regular data frames, they're much more convenient for this type of work.

If you'd rather stick with base `R` you can replace `data <- tibble::tibble(nodes, distances)` by:

```
data <- data.frame(distances)
data$nodes <- nodes
```

**new function**

```
generator <- function(n){
  nodes <- list()      # changed this from `c()` to `list()`
  distances <- c()
  for (main in 1:n){
    for (i in 1:n) {
      for (j in 1:n){
        if (main != i & i != j & main != j & i < j){
          nodes <- append(nodes, list(c(main, i, j))) # changed this to append a list instead of a vector
          distances <- c(distances, main+i+j)}}}}
  data <- tibble::tibble(nodes, distances) # changed `data.frame` to `tibble`
  return(data)}
```

**output**

```
df <- generator(4)

df
# A tibble: 12 x 2
#        nodes distances
#      <list>     <int>
#  1 <int [3]>         6
#  2 <int [3]>         7
#  3 <int [3]>         8
#  4 <int [3]>         6
#  5 <int [3]>         7
#  6 <int [3]>         9
#  7 <int [3]>         6
#  8 <int [3]>         8
#  9 <int [3]>         9
# 10 <int [3]>         7
# 11 <int [3]>         8
# 12 <int [3]>         9

df$nodes[[1]]
# [1] 1 2 3
```

**side note**

You're growing a list, which can be slow, if you run into performance issues try defining `nodes` with `nodes <- vector("list", length = max_length)` and trim it in the end with `nodes  <- nodes[lengths(nodes)!=0]`.